# Linux - How to stop users from moving folders

Tags: permissions, samba, directory

We have a situation where users in a factory are regularly moving folders from a shared samba drive, which in turn causes issues for the software running on the machines

For example, we have a root folder which is shared with all factory pc's

```
/usr/factory
```

and within that folder we have

```
/usr/factory/proc1
/usr/factory/proc2
/usr/factory/proc3
/usr/factory/proc4
```

And all of those proc folders contain sub-folders with the actual production data required for machines

In some cases, users are "accidentally" clicking and dragging folders away from their expected location. Since the software they use needs to be able to read and write back to the folders, we can't just remove all access. Additionally, since they access multiple folders, mapping directly to the folders isn't preferred either.

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't provided any OS & release details; but `/usr/` is a system directory and isn't usually shared.  Are you using a BSD system?

Comment: Moving the `/usr/factory/proc*` folders will require write permissions on `/usr/factory/`. Why do they need write permissions on `/usr/factory/`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the permissions type: **chown -R root:root /usr/factory**
where **root:root** is the argument to give permissions only to the root user.